# Why can not i get path of plist file in my project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, plist

I am using this function to get path of a plist file in my project:

```
 + (NSString *) appDataPath{
NSLog(@"in appDataPath");
NSString *appDPath = nil;
// Get the main bundle for the app.
NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

if (mainBundle != nil) {
    NSLog(@"in appDataPath mainbundle");
    appDPath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"MyAppSettings" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"appDataPath: %@", appDPath);
}

return appDPath;
}
```

It goes in if(mainBundle != nil) but appDPath is null. This same function is working in one other project. Why is it not working here? Is there any other way to get path of a plist file in project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there actually a file `MyAppSettings.plist` in the resources of your project ?

Comment: yup. there is MyAppSettings.plist in resources of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
+ (NSString *) appDataPath{

     NSString *plistPath;
     NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                   YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppSettings.plist"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
          plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyAppSettings" 
                                                      ofType:@"plist"];
         return plistPath;
    }
    else 
    // No plist found       
}
```

Comment: No plist found. whats the problem? i have plist MyAppSettings.plist in resources. and i checked case sensitivity as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check the case.  iOS' filesystem is case sensitive.

Check the file isn't in a directory.  You need to call `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory` in that case.

Check the file is enabled for the target you are building.  If it isn't, it won't get copied into the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

if by any chance you are having your plist in subfolder, then you should consider using

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ofType: inDirectory:]
```

by specifying the directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to find plist path in my project.

```
-(void)CreatePlistPath
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    path = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"] retain];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        NSString *bundle =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: and there is an exception that source path is nil

Comment: path is having datatype Nsstring so just declare it in .h file.. there is no need to initialize.